# If JSONP is used to workaround the same origin policy, can't it be used for XSS exploits?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I'm trying to understand how JSONP works, and from my so far very basic understanding, I feel like it's used to circumvent the same origin policy browsers enforce. I guess this main reason behind the policy is to prevent stuff like XSS exploits (where say someone could inject a script that makes use of the local cookies on a users machine to get valuable information, say when the user has logged into their bank account....is that right?) Now if JSONP is circumventing this policy, can't it be exploited for stuff like this? Sorry if this question is very basic....I just started trying to pickup javascript a few days back, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The real question is, do you trust that other domain? Since the other domain is essentially being given FULL access to your page (via JavaScript) you should be absolutely sure that you trust them. If they wanted they could quite easily vandalize your page, redirect the user, or worse: steal your cookies (which leads to a whole bunch of potential problems).

From: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jsonp-safe/

So, basically, yes, it can be used for XSS exploits. Therefore, it's important that you trust the host domain. If you're unsure about the integrity of the host domain, avoid using JSONP.

Answer (score 2):

When you use JSONP, you are trusting the hosting site not to inject evil code or to allow attackers to inject evil code.

So basically the answer is: Yes. If you don't have that level of trust, don't use JSONP from that site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can.  If you don't trust the third-party whose data you're requesting, or if someone can inject something in between, then don't use JSONP with it.  JSONP will allow arbitrary code from the third-party site to run on your page.

Answer (score 2):

JSONP is leveraging the fact that `script` tags can load data from externals domains. You are doing this all the time when you use CDNs for popular libraries.

So JSONP by itself does not make XSS exploits easier. The "problem" is that `script` tags can load arbitrary files and this has nothing to do with JSONP. Whenever you load external files, you have to be sure they do not contain malicious code.